# Adding CSS styles to OpenLayers Layer/Image instance

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have an Angular app with OpenLayers. I need to set a border on the layer (or any style, really), which is an instance of ol/layer/Image. The image itself is rendering perfectly fine, and the rest of the code works too.

```
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import Projection from 'ol/proj/Projection';
import { Image as ImageLayer } from 'ol/layer';
import { ImageStatic as Static } from 'ol/source';
import View from 'ol/View';
import { getCenter } from 'ol/extent';

// initialising class between these.
// this.map is an instance of "Map"
// setNewImage is a method within my class

 setNewImage(file, width, height, view) {
    const extent = [0, 0, width, height];
    const projection = new Projection({
      code: 'xkcd-image',
      units: 'pixels',
      extent,
    });
    const newView = new View({
      projection,
      center: view ? view.center : getCenter(extent),
      zoom: view ? view.zoom : 1,
      maxZoom: 8,
    });
    const layer = new ImageLayer({
      source: new Static({
        attributions: '©',
        url: file,
        projection,
        imageExtent: extent,
        imageSize: [width, height],
      }),
    });

    this.map.addLayer(layer);
    this.map.setView(newView);
}
```

"layer.values_" gives the values of ImageLayer properties. I can reach the instance of Static through "layer.values_.source", but there is nothing I could find that lets me alter CSS properties of this image, for example border-radius or box-shadow.

Comment: when you draw openlayer it draws you an canvas to display map in order to add above mentioned css properties you can add them div thich is displaying map, but you wont be able to add any css properties to image layer they way we generally do css.